# Permalinks in phpbb3

Tags: permalinks, phpbb3

I am trying to figure out a way to change the permalinks of my phpbb3 forums. Currently they have the typical, yet unsatisfactory for me, look:

`forum/viewtopic.php?f=XX&t=YY`

I have done some research online and I can only find bad and outdated mods. Does anyone have a  working mod or some hints on how to do this?

Thank you in advance everyone for your time.

Yours faithfully,
dwc

Comment: Noone can help? No clue? Zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these: http://www.phpbb-seo.com/

Comment: This worked! I am really impressed that there was some community still active on phpbb! Thank you very much! 

Heads up to anyone interested in using it too, the installation does not last 25 minutes, more like 150 mins. But it works like a charm!

Comment: the site is down.